# How to handle a String multi-selection with dynamic approvers in Power Automate Flow?

Tags: odata, power-automate

My MS Form includes a multi-selection question: "Interests". The responses for "Interests" could be 1~15. "Interests" list includes: Appliance, Auto Products, Beverage, Computer, Clothing, DVD, Electronics, Food, Grocery, Home Goods, Holiday Products, Industrial Products, Music, Medical Care, Video, and so on.

I need a flow to record all the responses from this form, including the responses for "Interests".

I also need another flow to handle a 'two level approval' process that is triggered by the response of "Interests". I have a SharePoint list to record approval responders' email. This list include three columns, first column is "Interests", the second column is "Supervisors_Email", and the third column is "Directors_Email". If the response is "Appliance, Computer, Music", then the flow will send the first level approval request to the Supervisors's email who are in charge of these three products, once they approve the request, the Directors' email will receive the email for the final approval.

I have created two flows to handle the single 'Interests' selection without any issues, but have been struggling with the multi-selection with dynamic approvers situation.  Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.